# UIView overlaps Status bar in ios 10

Tags: swift, uiview, scrollview

The pic itself is describing the issue. I have a `UIView` and a Nav bar and a `UIScrollview` nested inside it. When the Keyboard comes up to enter text, the UI scrolls behind the navigation bar (which is good) but then you see the UI at the top of the screen overlapping the status bar. How do i get it to be not visible beyond the navigation bar? Thanks. I am using Swift 2.x

[image]

Comment: delete your nav bar and embed in a nav controller

Comment: You need to use `.TopAttached` as the nav bar's positioning, as I describe here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30831452/341994 That will cause the nav bar to stretch up behind the status bar.

Comment: That helped. THanks.

Comment: Embedding in a Nav controller helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of you using navigation bar,you can also use `UIView` and place a `UILabel` for heading and `UIButton` for back button. In that very case your `UIView` that will act as custom header and scroll up with your scrollable view.
Also in Navigation bar, mark status bar as None from storyboard.